Продумать как можно вызвать документ из worda
Нужно автоматизировать процесс документооборота в клинике. Есть документ план лечения в word который составляет администратор к нему в процессе добавления услуг с кодами должен выскакивать еще один документ исходя и услуг которые там прописаны, как это можно реализовать ? Может в ворде прописать sql либо какой то другой вариант. Посоветуйте как поступить в данной ситуации.

Я бы переместил план в Excel, ну или хотя бы в ворде таблицу превратил в объект "Excel Sheet" - там попроще работать с таблицей и с внешними источниками данных. А уж ODBC-коннект к серверу MySQL - это вообще тривиальная задача.

Написать приложение, которое будет тянуть всю нужную инфу и по кнопке печатать или сохранять в word.

Все шаблоны документов сохраняются в формате rtf. Akina вы можете мне помочь с реализацией этой задачи ?

@yaroslav На сколько я помню, в rtf вы макрос не впихнете. нужен docx(там макросы на vba писать можно).

Давайте попробуем . Я прочитал что если  пропичать код в rtf формате , исходнике то может сработать. Можете помочь ?

Я прочитал что если пропичать код в rtf формате , исходнике то может сработать. Можете помочь ? Вы прочитали ерунду. Ну или неправильно поняли, что там было сказано. (надеюсь, помог)

Помочь то с чем? В rtf не работают макросы, а то что вы хотите должно работать в самом документе. Однако, как мне кажется, время, потраченное вами на решение этой задачи, сопоставимо с временем написания небольшого web приложения с возможностью сохранения данных в rtf

Как тогда решить вопрос  ?  если все документы по умолчанию храняться в файлах в формате rtf и поменять их никак.
